# link_to on an unsaved association in a loop causing path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link_to inside of an each loop.  The object that's being looped does indeed contain a new record (sometimes).   The parent object is a `book` and the nested object is `photo`.

```
- @book.photos.each do |photo|
  = link_to image_tag(photo.pic.url), edit_book_photo_path(@book)
```

And the error is, rather predictably:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos", :id=>nil, :book_id=>147, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I have tried checking for a new_record using:

```
- @book.photos.each do |photo|
  = link_to image_tag(photo.pic.url), edit_book_photo_path(@book) unless photo.new_record?
```

And

```
- @book.photos.each do |photo|
  - unless photo.new_record?
    = link_to image_tag(photo.pic.url), edit_book_photo_path(@book)
```

But get the same error.

That unless works fine if I'm not doing a link_to, for instance if I create a list

```
%ul
  - @book.photos.each do |photo|
    - unless photo.new_record?
      %li= "This is id #{photo.id}"
```

I see see that there are the correct number of child objects and removing the unless gives me one extra with no id.

So, clearly I'm making this overly complicated, because it should be simple or I've gone astray.  The GOAL::: Render a list of images (`@book.photos.pic`) on the `book`'s form, each image is a link to edit the `photo` record.

Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- @book.photos.select(&:persisted?).each do |photo|
  = link_to image_tag(photo.pic.url), edit_book_photo_path(@book, photo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding picture id:

```
- @book.photos.each do |photo|
  = link_to image_tag(photo.pic.url), edit_book_photo_path(@book, photo)
```

Comment: Beat me too it ! Damm

Comment: This doesn't do it, same error, lovely missing keys.  @narkoz nailed it with persisted.. I'm an idiot. :)